# Transparent menus(for applications) in gnome shell

Tags: gnome

How do I make menus look transparent in Gnome-shell?

In unity, I use ubuntu-tweak to do this(In ubuntu tweak , Go to Desktop->Compiz settings and then select Enable transparent menus option). Since compiz is no longer being used in gnome-shell, this is not working any more . Any alternatives ?

I love gnome-shell but I am still missing some awesome features of compiz like "wobbly windows" and other desktop effects!

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear in the above comment. By menus, I mean applications menu like nautilus menu, firefox menu etc (not gnome-shell menus)

Comment: What is to be edited in the CSS file BTW ?

Comment: oh. you need to make a comment on my answer so i can get the notification for that. :)  in this case i don't know the answer, sorry.

Comment: ok. thanks . I dont think its possible in gnome shell

Answer (score 1):

transparency of the menus and panel is controlled by the shell theme you are using.

you can modify it by:

- selecting another theme that has transparency.
- modifying the current theme to have transparency. you can modify the
  theme (not recommended if you don't know what you are doing) by going to to the theme .css file.( you can find the .css file in the `/home/username/.themes/theme you downloaded`.  or in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`
- if you modify any file, please be carefull and make sure to back up
  the original.

my suggestion is to use another theme to your liking. such as [elementaryviper luna](http://justviper.deviantart.com/art/ElementaryViper-Luna-shell-1-2-261144492). which is semi transparent.or the [elegance](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Gnome-Shell-Elegance-263626995) theme.

[image: elementaryviper luna screenshot]

for other themes available for gnome shell, you can go to [devianart](http://gnome-shell.deviantart.com/gallery/28081982) or to [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=191&PHPSESSID=c49bfd0eaca5dc5a5029182c4ae5b105)

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear in the above comment. By menus, I mean applications menu like nautilus menu, firefox menu etc (not gnome-shell menus)